# How to inherit resources from outer Window in an UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I start my WPF app per Windows Application `new Application().Run(new MainWindow())` - so I don't have an **app.xaml**

I have a main window, which contains any used UserControls per ContentControl

```
<Window ..>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
                <!-- ... -->
            <converter:BooleanToIntConverter x:Key="BooleanToIntConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding MyUserControl}" />
</Window>
```

**How can I inherit resources from my MainWindow to UserControls which are within iny MainWindow?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **resources** of the `Application` by accessing the `Resources` `ResourceDictionary`:

```
Application app = new Application();
app.Resources["MySharedResource"] = ...;
app.Resources["MyOtherSharedResource"] = ...;
app.Run(new MainWindow());
```

This is exactly what is done with the `App.xaml` file.